# Decrypting mp4 on the fly

Tags: java, android, encryption

Let me explain what I want to do.
I have a encrypted mp4 file that use AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding model. Now I put it to a myself web server for myself Android Network MediaPlayer to play it via Network streaming mp4.

I used CipherInputstream to decrypt the encrypted mp4 file and put to InputStreamEntity, but that did not work, so I need any suggestion how I can do.

Some codes,
...

```
public void InitCiphers()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchProviderException,
            NoSuchProviderException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{

   //1. create the cipher using Bouncy Castle Provider
   encryptCipher =
           Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
   //2. create the key
   SecretKey keyValue = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
   //3. create the IV
   AlgorithmParameterSpec IVspec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
   //4. init the cipher
   //encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
   encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyValue);

   //1 create the cipher
   decryptCipher =
           Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
   //2. the key is already created
   //3. the IV is already created
   //4. init the cipher
   //decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
   decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyValue);
}

public void CBCEncryptCipherStream(InputStream fis, OutputStream fos) throws IOException, ShortBufferException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    fos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, encryptCipher);

    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = fis.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        fos.write(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
    fos.close();
}

public InputStream CBCDecryptStream(InputStream encryptedInputStream){
    InputStream decryptedInputStream = null;
    decryptedInputStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptedInputStream, decryptCipher);
    return decryptedInputStream;

}
```

Then,

```
InputStream datastream = bcAES_CBC_128.CBCDecryptStream(new FileInputStream(encyptedPlayFile));

bodystream= new InputStreamEntity(datastream, filesize);

response.setEntity(bodystream);
bodystream.setContentType("video/mpeg");
```

Comment: The type of the file being decrypted is irrelevant.

Comment: Without example code illustrating the problem and defining "did not work" there's really not much anyone here can help you with.

Comment: Can you decrypt the file successfully on your device?  If you can't do that then trying to stream it will be a problem.

Comment: The encrypted file is decrypted to original file successfully by using the same decryption method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decrypt a mp4 on-the-fly in java application server for network streaming to Android MediaPlayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786120/how-to-decrypt-a-mp4-on-the-fly-in-java-application-server-for-network-streaming)